# Calculate percentage difference of gauge value over 5 minutes

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I would like to compare the same gauge metrics with itself.

Lets say i have a metric items_count_exported gauge. Gauge is updated every 5 minutes
I want to create and alert which can spot the difference between gauge generated 5 minutes ago and the one generated now and if there is a difference lets say 10% then alert will be triggered. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You can use `offset` to get a value from X minutes ago and calculate the percentage difference that way. Since it's a gauge, it can go in any direction and it might even be negative. You should get the absolute value with `abs()` to make sure the percentage changed is a positive number.

Query that gives you the percentage you want

```
100 * abs(items_count_exported - items_count_exported offset 5m) / abs(items_count_exported offset 5m)
```

Then create an alert that checks if the output of the query above is `> 10`.

If you want to know the direction of change (10% increase vs 10% decrease), then this query needs to be adapted a bit.